# How to import Eclipse user libraries into IntelliJ Idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have *lib.userlibraries* file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<eclipse-userlibraries version="2">
  <library name="MyLib" systemlibrary="false">
    <archive path=PATH_TO_LOCAL_JAR_1/>
    <archive path=PATH_TO_LOCAL_JAR_2/>
    ...
    <archive path=PATH_TO_LOCAL_JAR_100/>
  </library>
</eclipse-userlibraries>
```

I want to import these local jar files to the project in IntelliJ Idea. I can do it manually via File -> Project Structure... -> Libraries, but it will require to import each jar file separately. Is there automatic way to import this userlibraries file to IntelliJ Idea project?

Comment: I appreciate the accept . And welcome to "upvote" level ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer about using the IntelliJ import feature for eclipse projects should be your first "stop".

Beyond that: importing doesn't necessarily work for all projects. We have a large, complicated eclipse project. Trying to import that in IntelliJ simply didn't work (the module definition that IntelliJ created was completely wrong, and lead to thousands and thousands of build errors).

In that specific case, it might be *faster* to use a powerful text editor, like:

- open the eclipse .classpath file
- create a *new* IntelliJ project, and import maybe *one* of the required libraries manually
- open the corresponding module xyz.iml file
- simply compare/copy ( get the JAR file names from eclipse, and use editor magic to create the raw strings you need for the .iml file )

Of course, that seems silly, but as said: using a text editor, I got a large setup with 15 modules/projects to build fine in less than an hour.

And the **real** answer: base your project setup on a tool like maven or gradle. Because these tools allow you to **generate** eclipse or IntelliJ configuration files. If possible, always do that. Even when it means to learn a new tool, and a lengthy transition period.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ IDEA open the Eclipse project by [importing from Eclipse](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#migratingEclipseProject) wizard. It will give you an opportunity to select user libraries.

Comment: Nice and quick, and thanks for leaving some room for another answer ;-)